# How difficult is it to collect obd commands ?Will it be different for different brands?

Tags: obd-ii, diagnostics, dtc, obd, pid

OBD is something very interesting I found these days.Thanks to this repo https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api & wikipedia which provides the basic information of PIDs.But there is a lot of details missing like when the fault is in air bags it is left unidentified.

1. Some sources are saying that there are hundreds of more commands that helps to fetch more information about vehicle status from different sensors.How can I access them ,are they segregated brandwise?
2. Recently I came across a command 1800FF00 still I wonder which mode(service) it faults into(010C indicates mode 1).

It could be great if you share any docs that helps in exploring the vehicle diagnostics more.

Comment: Have you looked for this topic on here? there are several posts about this.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for your response,yeah I did go through most of them,but none of them had any mentions of commands and their decoding algorithm.So I just wanna figure out how complex is to grab all these data and work on the car diagnostics.Can you help me in this concern

Comment: Other than the minimum set of federally-mandated OBD-II commands, which are for the most part related to emissions, codes are proprietary and typically not published by the manufacturer. Depending on your make & model, you may be able to find more specific protocol & command data. Much of that will have to be captured from the CAN bus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a oscilloscope to get more precise sensor data, this allows you to view it in motion rather than just the error codes or functions status

Comment: Thanks for response,I did go through that but my major quest is to find how to figure out the faults using the obd commands.Because this gives the data in well served manner to a person with minimum mechanical knowledge.I read that oscilloscope gives data more effectively compared to obd,but I guess it requires some pre knowledge about vehicle mechanics to crack down the faults.Please correct me if I am wrong.I am just willing to trace out the dtcs stored in sensors which cannot be achieved just using(03 and 07) commands.

Comment: @Falcon so something like this http://www.tirereview.com/fuel-system-definitions-and-diagnostic-trouble-codes/

Comment: thanks,it says more about how to analyse and work on the fault code rather than how to obtain them.